# How to Manage Many-to-Many Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models `Group` and `Person` that I want to have a many-to-many relationship, but I'm unclear on how to manage the relationship itself. I want to be able to create groups and persons separately -- NOT necessarily via a nested model -- and then link persons to groups from the group view/model itself.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do so?

I thought of creating a many-to-many relationship via a join model and then accepting nested attributes for the join model in the `Group` model -- so I believe I will be able to add and remove relationships via the `Group` view/model. Does this approach make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `PersonGroup` model that looks like this:

```
class PersonGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  has_many :groups
end
```

And you might also do `rails generate migration create_person_group` and put this in the `up` method of the generated migration file:

```
create_table :person_group do |t| 
  t.integer :person_id, :null => false
  t.integer :group_id, :null => false

  t.timestamps
end 

add_index :person_group, [:person_id, :group_id], :unique => true
```

Then in `Person`:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :person_groups
end
```

And in `Group`:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_groups
  has_many :people, :through => :person_groups
end
```

Comment: Good answer, except the name of the join model.  The rails default is to use the name of the models in alphabetical order (i.e. GroupPerson), or to use a name that describes the relation (e.g. Membership, Grouping, or other -ship or -ing words).

Comment: Good point. I was aware of the latter convention but not the former. I would have preferred to have suggested a more meaningful table name, but I couldn't think of one. Perhaps the OP, knowing more about the domain than myself, will be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).  Junction tables are used when you want to store many-to-many relationships.  I don't develop in ROR so I don't know the specifics for ActiveRecord but I am sure that this can help you think about the problem as well.

```
group_id INTEGER,
person_id INTEGER
```